# Why does nvimtree keep changing to the wrong directory?

Tags: neovim, lsp, plugin-nvimtree, plugin-telescope

I have a project with the following structure.

[image]

It's a monorepo based react project. It opens fine in the beginning. But as soon as I open any file e.g. `apps/editor/pages/index.js`. The NVIMTree updates to the wrong root directory.
[image]

I have an LSP installed for my project, `tsserver`.
After changing of root the files that are not in that root don't show up in Telescope either.

I would have posted some config files but I am really not sure if it's an LSP issue, Telescope issue or NVIMTree issue.

Comment: It can be more than one thing and it difficult to asses to knowing your full configuration. I recommend that you deactivate some of your plugin in order to determine which one is the culprit. The following answer may help you in this search [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/23502).

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). The first image about your project structure could just be text, and the second could come with a more explicit description of the problem. Please [edit] to clarify why this is the "wrong" directory, etc.